# Does ASP.NET MVC4 provide backward compatibility support for HTML5 controls ?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a web site by using the html5 input controls. (email,search, tel, date..etc).

Do MVC 4 automatically provide support for older browsers like IE 8 or the developer has to explicitly write the fallbacks to support those controls in older browsers ?

Like for a  control, from the Mordernizr I can find whether it supports the control else fire a JQuery to show the calendar.

So, my question, using ASP.NET MVC 4 do we still have to write the fallbacks/workarounds to support in older browswer.

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Anirban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 5 won't work on older browsers so you would have to find a other way to achieve what you want to achieve.
MVC 4 does not change any of that.
I do know that MVC 4 has some buildin features to identify a browser which might help for making it compatibility across diffrent browser brands. But that is mostly to support mobile devices([Display modes](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/09/display-mode-in-mvc-4aspnet-mvc-4.html)).
If you really want to use HTML 5 you have to accept the fact that older browsers wont be able to display everything the way it is suppose to.
You might be interested in reading this article : http://html5tutorial.net/general/which-browsers-support-html5.html

**Edit**

MVC 4 will not detect if your browser will support the page. So it will not make a fallback either. MVC can tell you somewhat about what browser is being used etc but cannot know if it will be supported.

Comment: I know HTML5 wont be supported in older browsers. That was my question - Will ASP.NET MVC4 automatically detect and write the automatic fallbacks ?

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I downloaded MVC4 and checked that this is not possible. Anirban

Answer (score 3):

When you create a MVC4 project with Visual Studio, you will see modernizr-1.7.min.js file in your Scripts folder of the project.  This script helps you to support old browsers by gracially  downgrading the HTML sytax.  You can find more information about modernizr here:

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: +1 for good observation. My problem is the `@Htmlhelper.EditorFor` that generates `<input type='date' ...` for date fields which is a HTML5 input type, apparently modernizr doesn't convert this either:

http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css